# FormClosed event is not firing

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

```
private void GameForm_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    infform.Show();
}
```

GameForm has another form, infform. The form won't show when it closes. Something wrong here?

Comment: Did you register your form with the FormClosed event?

Comment: if infform is owned by GameForm, is it possibly being destroyed as GameForm is now closed?

Answer (score 0):

Could this help?

```
  private void GameForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Hide();
        infform.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing to keep in mind... when your main `form` closes, the entire application exits. If you want to catch that event, you can registre to `Application.ApplicationExit`.

This event is fired whenever the `Application` exits.